# Django intersection of ManyToMany using Through model

Tags: python, django

I have two models that have a ManyToMany relationship using a through model.

```
class Person(Model):
    departments = ManyToManyField('Department', through='DepartmentStaff')

class Department(Model):
    id = ...

class DepartmentStaff(Model):
    staff_member = ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=CASCADE)
    department = ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=CASCADE)
    experience = DurationField()
```

I want to check if 2 Person objects share at least one department. e.g. if person `p1` works in departments `d1` and `d2`, and Person `p2` works in departments `d2` and `d3`, then they both work in `d2`, the output should be `True`

I know that I can't do something like this

```
>>> p1.departments.intersection(p2.departments).exists()
...
AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'query'
```

because I'm using a through relationship. What is the best way to check if 2 through ManyToMany query sets contain at least one same element?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

`DepartmentStaff.objects.filter(staff_member='p1', department__in=DepartmentStaff.objects.filter(staff_member='p2'))`

Comment: Hmm, this here seems to always return an empty query set because the 2 query sets you use & on are mutually exclusive.

Comment: this fails because you're using DepartmentStaff as a query set for filtering department. The code raises a ValueError